# Android Studio/Xubuntu ADB Waiting

Tags: android, ubuntu

I've been working to setup android studio on xubuntu. I'm able to find the device manually on the terminal, but when ever I run the application on Android Studio I get ADB waiting until it stops responding.
Thanks for the help, Ryan

Answer (score 1):

The ADB daemon on the device itself might be the problem. Try to enter `adb shell` in the Terminal. That should give you shell access on the device. If you're able to use a command like `ls`, the ADB connection is working as intended.

If you're not able to open the shell or execute ls, the ADB daemon on the device is the problem. Try rebooting the device, and/or re-enabling USB Debugging.

If shell access is working as intended, Android Studio should work too. Try restarting Android Studio.